# My custom module shows up on the modules list but I cannot enable it, why?

Tags: .info

I've written a custom module (*custom_data_import*) with a .info.yml file and .module files, but the module only shows up in my list of modules and I cannot enable it. Moreover, the .module file seems to act like a plain text file. Can someone please help?

The content of the *custom_data_import.info.yml* file is the following.

```yaml
name: 'Custom Data Import'
type: module
description: 'Custom module to import JSON data'
package: Custom
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
dependencies:
  - drupal: node
  - drupal: http_client
```

Comment: What is your folder structure? What does [MODULE].info.yml look like?

Answer (score 3):

The dependencies are not correct. The [Http Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client) module is not a Drupal core module; that means it can be declared as dependency as `http_client:http_client`, not `drupal:http_client`. (There must be no space before or after colons.)

The dependency format is `<project machine name>:<module machine name>`. The project machine name is the last part in the project page URL, `https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client` for the *Http Client* module and `https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal` for Drupal core.

Since you are defining the dependency as `drupal:http_client`, and since Drupal doesn't find any Drupal core module with that machine name, Drupal does not allow you to install your custom module because one of the dependencies is missing. (As far as I recall, it should show a note about the missing dependency in the module description.)

Comment: Thanks so much! That was a terrible oversight on my part, but I changed it now. However, the module now doesn't appear on the list at all!

Comment: Did you install the *Http Client* module?

Comment: I did, still doesn't work!

Comment: If you edited the .info.yml which is already copied on the server, Drupal probably did not notice the change. (Keep in mind that some information is cached by Drupal.)